# Viewing sizes based on the product ID

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to figure out how to display a drop down of sizes dependent on the product id. I have a product tbl which holds information and a productdetails tbl which has a productid as the foreign key, the sizes and units in stock.

I would like to display only the sizes which are available to each particular product.

**Product Display Code**

```
<?php while ($row = $stmt->    fetch()) { ?>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="productimage">
<img src="<?= $row['pimage'] ?>" alt="<?= $row['name'] ?>" onclick="window.location.href = '../Controller/Expand.php?id=<?= $row['productid'] ?>'">   
</div>
<div class="caption">                        
<h5><?= $row['name'] ?></h5>
<h6> <select name="size" id="size">                               
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
<option><?= $row['size'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select></h6>
<br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Display Shop**

```
   <?php

require_once 'DatabaseConnection.php';

extract($_GET);
  $sql = "SELECT
  Product.name,
  Product.colour,
  Product.unitprice,
  Product.pimage,
  Product.unitweight,
  ProductDetails.unitsinstock,
  ProductDetails.size,
  Product.discount,
  Product.productid,
  ProductDetails.productid
  FROM
  Product,
  ProductDetails
  WHERE
  Product.productid=ProductDetails.productid
  AND
  ProductDetails.unitsinstock>0";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql) or die(implode(':', $stmt->errorInfo()));
  $stmt->execute() or die(implode(':', $stmt->errorInfo()));
  $cols = $stmt->columnCount();
```

**Sizes.Controller**

```
    <?php
    require_once 'DatabaseConnection.php';
    $smt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ProductDetails.size, ProductDetails.productid, Product.productid 
FROM ProductDetails, Product 
WHERE unitsinstock>0 
AND ProductDetails.productid=Product.productid");
    $smt->execute();
    $data = $smt->fetchAll();
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What's your query in `product display code`?

Comment: It runs the query in the Display Shop code printed below.

Comment: Try changing `$row = $stmt->fetch()` to `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Tried the (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) but I still have the same output. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried on my localhost. I've created two mysql tables (product and productdetails) and this is simplified template for extracting product size from productdetails for every product.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shop', 'root', 'root'); // root is username and also password :)

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM product") or die(implode(':', $stmt->errorInfo()));
$stmt->execute() or die(implode(':', $stmt->errorInfo()));

$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM productdetails");
$stm->execute();

$data = $stm->fetchAll();

while ($product = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>". $product['name'] ."</li>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($data as $details) {
            if($product['productid'] == $details['productid']) {
                echo "<li>" . $details['size'] . "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

This code works on my localhost.

Comment: Hi @MatijaLukic, thank you for your reply. It works now :D!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see both SELECT queries are the same.
I think that your $stmt query should be:

```
SELECT pimage, name, product_id FROM Product;
```

Result of this query should be in variable $row;

That query is going to return you all products.
While loop will catch one row with product_id, for example 1.
Then in foreach loop you should have $data which is query result of:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductDetails;
```

$data have all products from table ProductDetails
Each row from $data is $details.
Then you can filter product with php:

```
<?php if($row['product_id'] == $details['product_id']) {
<option>
<?php echo $details['size']; ?>
</option>
} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @MatijaLukic I have read your answer and came up with the following code in my main Shop.php page: 

'code' <h6> <select name="size" id="size">         
<?php foreach ($data as $details): ?>
<?php if ($row['productid'] == $details['productid']) { ?>
<option>
<?= $details['size']; ?>
</option>
<?php }
endforeach
?>
</select></h6>                    

However, now no sizes display on the page... :(, Is it possible you could spot an error in my code? As i am unsure of where I'm going wrong.